# equivalent of a python dict in R

Tags: python, r, dictionary

I want to make the equivalent of a python dict in R. Basically in python, I have:

```
visited = {}

if atom_count not in visited:
  Do stuff
  visited[atom_count] = 1
```

The idea is, if I saw that specific, atom_count, I have `visited[atom_count] = 1`. Thus, if I see that atom_count again, then I don't "Do Stuff". `Atom_Count` is an integer.

Thanks!

Comment: See the R package `hash` with its almost Python-like access functions.

Comment: @Chase which would cost O(n). Dict element access is constant.

Answer (score 99, accepted):

The closest thing to a python dict in R is simply a list. Like most R data types, lists can have a names attribute that can allow lists to act like a set of name-value pairs:

```
> l <- list(a = 1,b = "foo",c = 1:5)
> l
$a
[1] 1

$b
[1] "foo"

$c
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

> l[['c']]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5
> l[['b']]
[1] "foo"
```

Now for the usual disclaimer: they are not *exactly* the same; there will be differences. So you will be inviting disappointment to try to literally use lists exactly the way you might use a dict in python.

Comment: how can you programmatically iterate through such a list? the naive `l$names(l)[1]` obviously fails. i also haven't been able to get `l[which()]` to work

Comment: @MikePalmice Aside from a `for` loop, which is sort of an option in pretty much every language around, there is `lapply`. There are also related things with different syntax, like `Map`, and a whole package, **purrr** for lots of functional programming stuff.

Comment: @MikePalmice, I think `l[[names(l)[1]]` should work. Anyway, you can just iterate like this: `l[[1]]` without using the names.

Notice that single brackets `[]` will return a list, while double brackets `[[]]` will return the object inside the list.

Comment: wow, such a simple thing in other languages is difficult in r? Let us say I have string contained in a variable. If I try to make it a key, it just picks the variable name as the key name instead of the value of the variable.

Comment: @wondim You can set list item names from a variable with `names(list) <- vector_of names`, subsetted assignment works as well, `names(list)[1] <- "foo"`. See also `setNames()`.

Comment: @joran thanks! My challenge is populating it in a loop.

Comment: I tried using functions as first class members of my list, like I sometimes would in Python. That failed miserably, as every time I try to call the functions I get "Error: attempt to apply non-function".

Comment: @David `l <- list(a = sum,b = mean); l$a(1:3); l[['b']](1:3)` works I think.

Answer (score 13):

If, like in your case, you just want your "dictionary" to store values of the same type, you can simply use a vector, and name each element.

```
> l <- c(a = 1, b = 7, f = 2)
> l
a b f 
1 7 2
```

If you want to access the "keys", use `names`.

```
> names(l)
[1] "a" "b" "f"
```

Answer (score 5):

I believe that the use of a hash table (creating a new environment) may be the solution to your problem.  I'd type out how to do this but I just did so yesterday day at talkstats.com.

If your dictionary is large and only two columns then this may be the way to go.  Here's the link to the talkstats thread with sample R code:

[HASH TABLE LINK](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/25761-Evidence-that-data.table-isn-t-always-fastest?p=84805&viewfull=1#post84805)

Comment: Note `data.table` and R's own named vector look ups have improved drastically in speed since this time.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
visited <- list()  
if (!(atom_count %in% names(visited))) {  
 Do stuff  
 visited[[as.character(atom_count)]] <- 1  
}
```