# How to use a dictionary for a large data frame in R?

Tags: r

I read the answers about creating dictionary in r.

[equivalent of a python dict in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678872/equivalent-of-a-python-dict-in-r)

[Is there a dictionary functionality in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818970/is-there-a-dictionary-functionality-in-r)

And I have a question: how could I use this in a large dataset?
Data structure is like this:

[image]

dput of a subsample is:

```
structure(list(...1 = c("category 1", NA, NA, NA, "total", "category 2", 
NA, NA, NA, "total"), Items = c("product 1", "product 2", "product 3", 
"product 4", NA, "product 1", "product 2", "product 3", "product 4", 
NA), price = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 18)), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And I want the result be like:

categoryx: {prodcut1:1, product2:2, product3:3....}

What could I do if the there are 1000 categories and the number of products for each category is different? The answers in above two links, values of each key should be added manually, I don't how to use it for a large dataset.

Or is there other method (except create dictionaries) that could let me extract information of each category easily?

Could someone give ideas about this question? Thanks.

Is it possible to have a result like a dictionary(or list) of dictionaries in python?

such as dict={category1: {prodcut1:1, product2:2, product3:3....}, category2: {prodcut1:3, product2:4, product3:5....} }

So I could know categories's index and use the index to extract information from dict, and maybe it is like such a dataframe:

```
            item      price

categoryx    product1   2
             product2   3
```

so I could do operations for specific category?

Comment: The data structures `dictionary`, `set` doesn't have an exact structure in `R`.  Closest is named `list` or a json structure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A list of `hashmap` dictionaries:

```
dat <-
  structure(
    list(
      ...1 = c("category 1", NA, NA, NA, "total", "category 2",
               NA, NA, NA, "total"),
      Items = c(
        "product 1",
        "product 2",
        "product 3",
        "product 4",
        NA,
        "product 1",
        "product 2",
        "product 3",
        "product 4",
        NA
      ),
      price = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 3, 4, 5, 6, 18)
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,-10L),
    class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
  )

library(hashmap)

dat_clean <- tidyr::fill(dat[!is.na(dat[["Items"]]), ], 1)

list_of_dicts <- lapply(split(dat_clean, dat_clean[[1]]), function(d){
  hashmap(d[["Items"]], d[["price"]])  
})

list_of_dicts
# $`category 1`
# ## (character) => (numeric)  
# ## [product 1] => [+1.000000]
# ## [product 3] => [+3.000000]
# ## [product 4] => [+4.000000]
# ## [product 2] => [+2.000000]
# 
# $`category 2`
# ## (character) => (numeric)  
# ## [product 1] => [+3.000000]
# ## [product 3] => [+5.000000]
# ## [product 4] => [+6.000000]
# ## [product 2] => [+4.000000]


# get totals:
lapply(list_of_dicts, function(dict){
  sum(dict$values())
})
# $`category 1`
# [1] 10
# 
# $`category 2`
# [1] 18
```

Comment: And you could get keys of each category using: `keys(list_of_dicts$`category 1`)`, the result would be `[1] "product 1" "product 2" "product 3" "product 4"`

Comment: get values `values(list_of_dicts$`category 1`)`, and result is `product 1 product 2 product 3 product 4 
        1         2         3         4 `

Comment: thank you very much. And for users with Version 1.2.5019, could use hash instead of hashmap(already be removed from CRAN). And the code could be: `list_of_dicts <- lapply(split(dat_clean, dat_clean[[1]]), function(d){
  hash(d[["Items"]], d[["price"]])  
})` and `lapply(list_of_dicts, function(dict){
  sum(values(dict))
})`

Comment: @ling `hashmap` is removed from CRAN?? Not cool. It is very performant. And I don't see any substantial interest of `hash` as compared to an ordinary `list` (with a `list` you can simply use `names` to get the keys).

Comment: Yes, what a pity. however, `hash` could create the dictionaries. and `values(dict)`  in `hash` is the `dict$values()` in `hashmap`

Comment: @ling I think an ordinary list is faster than `hash`. And with an ordinary list, you can do `unlist(dict)` to get the values. Even faster, use a list of vectors instead of a list of dictionaries/lists.

Answer (score 2):

The first column name started with `...`, so it was `rename`d to 'grp', then use `fill` from `tidyr` to replace the `NA` elements with the previous non-NA element, `filter` out the rows where the 'Items' are `NA`, `unite` the columns 'Items', 'price' to a single column by concatenating with `sep` as ":", grouped by 'grp', we `summarise` the 'ItemsPrice' by creating a single string with `str_c`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   rename(grp = `...1`) %>% 
   fill(grp) %>%
   filter(!is.na(Items)) %>% 
   unite(ItemsPrice, Items, price, sep=":") %>%
   group_by(grp) %>%
   summarise(ItemsPrice = str_c(ItemsPrice, collapse = ", "))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
#  grp        ItemsPrice                                        
#  <chr>      <chr>                                             
#1 category 1 product 1:1, product 2:2, product 3:3, product 4:4
#2 category 2 product 1:3, product 2:4, product 3:5, product 4:6
```

Comment: Thanks! And if I want to do operations in each category, such as calculate total price of several products in one category, should I extract the category, then convert it to data frame? Because I found products' information is all in one row for one category in output here.

Comment: @ling As I mentioned in the comments, it is not clear about the expected output

Comment: @ling: You should avoid creating structures like that. Instead learn to use database methods. The best way to proceed would be to fill in the missing entries in the category column, possibly with `zoo::locf` and throw away the totals. They can be calculated later and you can display the results with `ftable` or other reporting functions, but leave the data in a normalized form.

Comment: @IRTFM Understand. I will try. Thank you!

Comment: @IRTFM The method from above answer also works. This could remove total row and add fill all NA in category with categoryx. and maintain orginal dataset's form. The code is `dat_clean1 <- tidyr::fill(df[!is.na(df[["Items"]]), ], 1)`

Comment: @ling: I didn't say it didn't "work". I said it wasn't a good idea to go this route. It will result in a data structure that is much more difficult to manipulate.

Comment: @IRTFM Oh, sorry for causing misunderstanding. The code in my answer is just an alternative method of zoo::locf, I add this as a note for anyone who view this question and want to fill in the missing entries as you mentioned. Thank you for your helpful idea.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zoo::na.locf` to fill the `category` values

```
names(df)[1] <- 'category'
df$category <- zoo::na.locf(df$category)
df <- subset(df, category != 'total')
df

# A tibble: 8 x 3
#  category   Items     price
#  <chr>      <chr>     <dbl>
#1 category 1 product 1     1
#2 category 1 product 2     2
#3 category 1 product 3     3
#4 category 1 product 4     4
#5 category 2 product 1     3
#6 category 2 product 2     4
#7 category 2 product 3     5
#8 category 2 product 4     6
```

I would keep the data as above in long format since all the libraries and base R allow grouped operations. So you can calculate anything for each `category`. I don't see any benefit of complicating the structure beyond this.

If you want the data to be in separate dataframes we can use `split`.

```
list_df <- split(df[-1], df$category)
```

Now you can have access to each individual category in separate dataframe. For example, to get data for `category 1` you can do :

```
list_df$`category 1`

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#  Items     price
#  <chr>     <dbl>
#1 product 1     1
#2 product 2     2
#3 product 3     3
#4 product 4     4
```